# How to pass events in the SLATEJS rich text editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, editor, rich-text-editor, slatejs

I'm trying coding follow this doc:

https://docs.slatejs.org/walkthroughs/05-executing-commands

I just wanted to make it elegant, so I tried to separate the Toolbar Button into other files. But how do I pass the event onKeydown there?

I tried the following code, but I got the result that 'editor is undefined'

**Did I overlook something?**

Here is a simple DEMO:

```
exprot function App(){
 //...others

 const [editor] = useState(() => withReact(createEditor()));
 return (
   <Slate {...props} >
     <MyToolbar {...editor} />
     //...others
   </Slate>
 );
}
function MyToolbar(editor: ReactEditor){
   return (
      <div>
        //Icon button span
        <span {...props} onMouseDown={event => {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            CustomEditor.toggleBold(editor);
                    }}></span>
      </div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass `editor` as a prop, use the hook [`useSlate()`](https://docs.slatejs.org/libraries/slate-react#useslate) to get it:

```
import { useSlate } from "slate-react";

function MyToolbar() {
  const editor = useSlate();

  return (
    <div>
      <span
        onMouseDown={event => {
          event.preventDefault();
          CustomEditor.toggleBold(editor);
        }}
      ></span>
    </div>
  );
}
```